# How to split this string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have this code

```
lStock.setText(" Put " + getLoc(i));
```

At the moment it prints out like this on the GUI:

```
3I031C
```

what I want to show now on the screen GUI is:

```
3I03-1C
```

I tried testing the `split()` but I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the split method since it needs a delimiter, but you're string doesn't contain any.

You can try using substring:

```
str = str.substring(0, 4) + "-" + str.substring(4);
```

But this will only work if the string always have the same length and format.

Answer (score 2):

[`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is used to break apart a string based on some particular delimiter.  You don't have a delimiter here.

If you always want to break after the fourth character:

```
String str = "3I031C";
String out = str.substring(0, 4) + '-' + str.substring(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If its a fixed output try like below

```
s = s.substring(0, 4) + "-" + s.substring(4);
```

refer to [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)